# Grant permission to grant only certain roles to a user

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-grant

I have role A and role B, I want to give the permission to some users to give role A to another user, but not role B.
Actually I'm using `GRANT GRANT ANY ROLE TO user`, but it allows user to give whatever role he wants.

So basically I need something like `GRANT GRANT A TO username`.

EDIT: The role that user has to grant to another user, it's not the role he belongs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those users you are trying to give that permission can belong to both roles, you can use `WITH GRANT OPTION` when granting the role you want to allow the grantee to be able to grant:

```
GRANT A TO user WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT B TO user;
```

Therefore, `user` will be able to grant role A but not role B (while he will belong to both).

EDIT: The scenario you now specified (allowing an user to grant a role to others without belonging to it) is not possible in Oracle except in the case in which that user is the one who created the role. According to Oracle Docs (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9013.htm#SQLRF01603) “To grant a role, you must either have been granted the role with the `ADMIN OPTION` or have been granted the `GRANT ANY ROLE` system privilege, or you must have created the role.”